# How to unmarshal JSON with array of key-value structs where key is does not have json tag

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm having troubles with unmarshalling the following json:

```
{
    "input-1": [
        "S",
        15.0,
        "some1",        
        [
            [
                1111111.357,
                "QQ",
                "Toronto"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "input-2": [
        "EE",
        90.1,
        "some2",
        [
            [
                55555550.705,
                "RR",
                "Kuala Lumpur"
            ],
            [
                22233330.134,
                "OO",
                "Bogota"
            ]           
        ]
    ],
    "input-3": [
        "UU",
        87.0,
        "some99",       
        [
            [
                8800221.500,
                "LL",
                "Lagos"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

My corresponding code looks like this:

```py
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type InputC struct {
    Type                string
    SomeFloat           float64
    CorrespondingPerson string
    Desc                []Under
}
type Under struct {
    IDCity   float64
    CityType string
    CityName string
}
func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("data.json", os.O_RDONLY, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error opening file: %v\n", err)
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading file: %v\n", err)
    }

    inputs:= map[string]InputC{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &inputs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error Unmarshalling file: %v\n", err)
    }

    for k, v := range(inputs) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n",v.Desc[0].IDCIty)
    }
}
```

Response I'm receiving from this code is:

> Error Unmarshalling file: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.InputC panic: runtime error: index out of range

After which I changed my code to this:

```
    inputs:= []InputC{}
```

but still got an error:

> Error Unmarshalling file: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.InputC

It's pretty obvious that I am missing something, but I cannot get idea how to extract info from JSON that I have.

Comment: You cannot unmarshal Mixed arrays into anything but []interface{}. From there it is type assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid having to use `[]interface{}` if you implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface on your custom structs and use `[]json.RawMessage` to temporarily hold the values of the individual array elements. Keep in mind that the solution below heavily relies on the number and order of the array's values to be guaranteed.

```
type InputC struct {
    Type                string
    SomeFloat           float64
    CorrespondingPerson string
    Desc                []Under
}

func (c *InputC) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(s) != 4 {
        return errors.New("something's off")
    }

    dest := []interface{}{&c.Type, &c.SomeFloat, &c.CorrespondingPerson, &c.Desc}
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(s[i], dest[i]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

type Under struct {
    IDCity   float64
    CityType string
    CityName string
}

func (u *Under) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s []json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(s) != 3 {
        return errors.New("something's off")
    }

    dest := []interface{}{&u.IDCity, &u.CityType, &u.CityName}
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if err := json.Unmarshal(s[i], dest[i]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/qpnvETC18rp

(Note that the floats printed in the playground *only look* different because that's how the package `fmt` prints floats by default when using the `%v` verb. E.g. this `fmt.Printf("%v", 1111111.357)` outputs `1.111111357e+06`.)